# Allowing some parts of a page to work when regular Expression validator returns invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am using a asp regular expression validation like so :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" MaxLength="13" onkeydown="return jsDecimals(event);"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" CssClass="valid"
    ErrorMessage="ID must be 13 Numeric characters" ControlToValidate="TextBox2" ValidationExpression="^[0-9]{13}$">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

it works fine but then if the user input is invalid all the links do not work, i would like to allow some of the controls to work in case the user decides to not continue with whatever task they are doing but I dont know how.

Comment: Have you tested CauseValidation = false for elements that must work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is `ValidationGroup`. You can assign different Buttons and Validators their own group so that one form does not interfere with another when clicking a Button

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" MaxLength="13"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" CssClass="valid"
    ErrorMessage="ID must be 13 Numeric characters" ControlToValidate="TextBox2" ValidationGroup="myGroup" ValidationExpression="^[0-9]{13}$">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
<br />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" ValidationGroup="myGroup" />


<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" MaxLength="13"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" CssClass="valid"
    ErrorMessage="ID must be 13 Numeric characters" ControlToValidate="TextBox3" ValidationGroup="anotherGroup" ValidationExpression="^[0-9]{13}$">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
<br />
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" ValidationGroup="anotherGroup" />
```